# Fastest way to query a SQL Database from Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, optimization, reporting

I will be building a little adding from Excel that would enable
to let user perform ad-hoc reporting from Excel.

the obvious way would be via SQL statement against an ODBC DataSource,
but I'm afraid it would not scale really well against a huge table (ie: doing a SUM or a COUNT against a table containing 50 gigas of datas will lead to performance issue)

I've been thinking about using some sort of caching technique, and basically querying in RAM
data : http://www.yellowfinbi.com/wp_inmemory.pdf
This can be costly in RAM and I'm not too sure how difficult it's to implement yet.

My Constraints are as follow :

- I should be able to query any type of Data Source (SQL Server, MySql) from Excel
- The ad-hoc reporting will be performed from an Excel (via my add-in)
- The query result should be send back to Excel cells as fast as possible
- I don't want to build Datawarehouse or Olap cubes, but query the data source

Any suggestions on algorithms, implementation techniques (In-Ram reporting ?) to have the most optimized way to perform ad-hoc querying form Excel ? (beside theoptimized SQL code!)

Comment: I'd suspect that RDBMS implementors have already put substantial effort into improving the performance of these aggregated operations within the RDBMS (it may depend on the actual system and configuration). I'd be surprised if pulling the data into Excel (presumably into RAM) could do any better (especially if you don't have 50GB of RAM). Do you tend to do these queries on a specific subset that you could cache, at least?

Comment: The time required for the transfer of data between the RDBMS and your Excel plugin (if the amount is as large as you say), even excluding the computation of the aggregated value and/or storage to RAM would also undoubtedly exceed the time it would take for doing this operation within the RDBMS itself, and only then transferring the aggregated result.

Comment: Isn't your concern with ODBC/SQL more about usability (for Excel users who wouldn't know SQL or the fact that you seem to be looking for something compatible with different types of SQL servers), rather than the scalability?

Comment: You are going to have difficulty because "I don't want to build DW or OLAP", is at odds with "50 gigas of datas" "as fast as possible".  you can't pull 50 gb of raw data across to a client and expect any kind of speedyness.  The only way you can hope to get any kind of decent performance is to build something server side/DB side to preaggregate and/or filter to sift that down to a smaller amount.

Comment: PowerPivot is the closest thing I know of to what you want, but it's still going to be slow with such a massive amount of data as it will be building cubes on the client side and will require a massive amount of ram.

Comment: Bruo : user won't have to know SQL, it's going to be generate on the fly based on what they would ask on the excel UI, so my issue is about scalability

Answer (score 2):

PowerPivot is one option which is a free addin for Excel that is optimized for aggregating(summing/counting) data in this sort of way.

It does require sufficient RAM to cache the data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

"(ie: doing a SUM or a COUNT against a table containing 50 gigas of datas will lead to performance issue)"

This is exactly why you probably don't want to cache the data at the client.  Unless each user has his own small supercomputer with 64 gb of RAM, then you need to reduce the number of rows coming across.

The fact is most users find a large report to be pretty useless.  Our brains can only keep less than a dozen values in short term memory.  Thus a user isn't going to be able to gleen anything useful from a huge amount of data.

They need to perform analysis, and usually analysis involves **aggregated or filtered data**.

Two options you can use either or in combo:

1) Implement views that pre-aggregate the data.  Many DB engines have something like materialized views or the no expand option in SQL server that basically let's you pre-aggregate reports.  **If you are trying to avoid this, and let your addin handle this, then you are basically building a OLAP engine, and should look at algorithms used by OLAP systems(this is exactly what PowerPivot is already).**

The idea is you let the DB engine do what it's good at, reduce the number of rows to an aggregated amount that's closer to what the client needs.  This ensures that you are not sending a huge amount of data over the network and requiring the client to process that data and cache in ram.

2) Pass filter criteria with the WHERE criteria/SP parameters to reduce the number of rows returned only to those absolutely needed.  There is room to get really creative here, more than most people reallize.  For example, maybe your table contains some data the user wouldn't have access to, so it makes sense to join with the authorization table(or whatever mechanism you use for access control) and filter out any data he does not have access to.

Require the user to choose filters to filter the data down to a reasonable amount.

It is a common occurrence that a user will want more data than they can swallow.